# Vaadin Clojure Widget Compilation without Maven

Tags: java, gwt, maven, clojure, vaadin

I am developing an application using clojure and vaadin. I am trying to use the ace editor widget from vaadin add-ons. I have added the maven repo to my leiningen file and I can get the jar just fine, However when I try to use it I get a,

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation for org.vaadin.aceeditor.AceEditor. 
Check its @ClientWidget mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and 
re-compile your widgetset.
```

error on the browser. Their documentation assumes everyone either uses maven or eclipse. So my question is what exactly does the eclipse plugin is doing behind the scenes so I can write a script to emulate that in leiningen? (I am not familiar neither with GWT or maven)

Comment: If you want to use a script, you should use Maven, since it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

GWT Compiler is just a Java application that can be run with Ant for example. You can find an example of Ant script that compiles widgetset from [here](https://vaadin.com/netbeans/build-widgetset.xml). The Ant script uses some Netbeans specific stuff but it should be easy to modify it so that it doesn't depend on Netbeans.